# fragmentTransaction.add() method issue

Tags: android

I saw that there were several questions regarding this topic, but I still can't understand. Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) states that you can add a fragment like this:

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment(); fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); fragmentTransaction.commit();`

but when I tried this to my code it just doesn;t find `.add()` method...

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myContainer, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
}
```

**MyFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


    public MyFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**activity_main**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    tools:context="com.example.alin.lynda_fragments008.MainActivity">



</FrameLayout>
```

**my_fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.alin.lynda_fragments008.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello from a fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `getFragmentManager()` into `getSupportFragmentManager()`;

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, but please provide detailed explanation also, e.g. "You are using `Fragment` class from support packages, but `FragmentManager` class from framework. Either use manager from support packages also (i.e. `getSupportFragmentManager()`) or use `Fragment` class from framework, not from support packages."

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to use the SupportFragmentManager. You most likely have some other issue. The method add is available as per the documentation. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)

Are you using Android Studio?
You should be able to see the suggestions of the methods once you type fragmentTransaction.(cmd+space on OSX)

Comment: Using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` mandates using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`, which OP neglects.

Comment: You're right.. My bad I didn't see him using the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`